# Equivalent of observeOn and subscribeOn in Kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

For example:

```
Observable.fromCallable<Int> {
   backgroundTask() // returns an integer
   }
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
   .subscribe ({ number -> /* success */ }, { error -> /* fail */ })
```

Generally *doing a task on the background (another thread) and getting the result of it back in the main thread.*

How will this code snippet be using **Kotlin coroutines**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can switch thread using `withContext()`. For example,

```
launch(Dispatchers.MAIN) {
    //main thread here
    val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        //IO thread here
        backgroundTask()
    }
    //main thread here again
    //doing something with result
}
```

Comment: instead of the labeled local return, `backgroundTask()` alone should work too, no?